# Elasticsearch query on parent child using facet count for matching results from both parent and child

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, facet

The idea is to perform a query on everything that matches a basic query statement and **return a facet count**

The children matched of type **page (child)** and then the count of the **book (parent)**. Use case of this would be to show X amount of books on Y amount of pages. These would then have seperates links, with additional queries etc.

I'm fresh out of the box with elasticsearch, very cool what I've got into so far, hit a brick wall with this, any help would be really useful.

Thank you for your time :)

```
{
  "query": {
  "has_child": {
    "type": "page",
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "text",
            "query": "some example search query"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "facets": {},
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
  }
}
```

*Yes, I've read the documentation on facets*

Comment: I'm not really sure what question you're asking? Are you asking how to do faceting or are you doing faceting and having a problem with it?

Comment: I've tried various things to try and count the matching children (the pages) which in turn return the has_child will return all the matching parents (the book) but I can't get it right.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/Fzct-MdUtTw